# Knockout model binding technique

Tags: knockout.js

I have this knockout view model for insert, update, delete and show citys

```
function City(data) {
    this.CityId = ko.observable(data.CityId);
    this.CityName = ko.observable(data.CityName);
}
function CityViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Citys = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedCity = ko.observable();
    self.EditingCity = ko.observable(new City({ CityId: '', CityName: '' }));

    self.EditCity = function (city) {
        $.ajax("/Controller/GetSingalCity/" + ko.toJSON(city.CityId), {
            data: ko.toJSON({ CityId: city.CityId }),
            type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    var cityid = result.Data.CityId;
                    var cityname = result.Data.CityName;
                    self.EditingCity(new City({ CityId: cityid, CityName: cityname }));
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error..");
                }
            }
        }); 
    };
}
```

with this code every time insert update delete I have to use use

```
self.EditingCity(new City({ CityId: cityid, CityName: cityname }));
```

Or

```
self.EditingCity(new City({ CityId: '', CityName: '' }));
```

I dont want to crate self.EditingCity(new City({ CityId: '', CityName: '' })); for every operation(insert,update, delete). can any one show me the way how ??
I am beginner with knockout....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new City object. Instead, just update the existing one. Any views that are data-bound to that `EditingCity` object should be automatically updated.

So, instead of writing:

```
self.EditingCity(new City({ CityId: cityid, CityName: cityname }));
```

You should be writing:

```
self.EditingCity().CityId(newCityId);
self.EditingCity().CityName(newCityName);
```

Comment: Patrick, I believe you wanted :

self.EditingCity().CityId(newCityId);
self.EditingCity().CityName(newCityName);

since EditingCity is an observable.  (Note the parens after EditingCity )